# Returning tuples from a method results in cumbersome usage pattern

Tags: c#, tuples, c#-7.0

I've been playing with returning tuples from methods, so method signatures like this...:

```
private int GetAlpha() {...} // -1 indicates an error
private bool GetAlpha(out int alphaOut) {...}
```

...turn into this:

```
private (bool Success, int Alpha) GetAlpha() {...}
```

**PROS:**

- I like avoiding the use of out-of-band values like `-1` to signal an error to the caller
- I've been reading recently that `out` parameters are evil and to be avoided

**CONS:**

- I can only use the `var (success, a, b, ...) = Foo(...)` syntax ONCE in a typical method. Thereafter, I'm forced to declare nearly all variables in the returned tuple, because 'success' is already defined
- I not only have to declare return variables, but I also have to explicitly specify their type (vs. implicitly using `var`).

```
var (success, alpha) = GetAlpha();
if (success)
{
    //var (success, beta, gamma) = GetStuff(alpha);      // ERROR - 'success' is already defined

    //(success, beta, gamma) = GetStuff(alpha);          // ERROR - 'beta' and 'gamma' are undefined

    //(success, var beta, var gamma) = GetStuff(alpha);  // ERROR - no such syntax, silly!

    string beta;
    DateTime gamma;
    (success, beta, gamma) = GetStuff(alpha);
        .
        .
        .
```

The convenience and conciseness of using the implicit declaration and typing is so nice, that it bugs me I'm typically only able to use it once in a method.

Am I missing anything? Is there some other pattern that avoids this?

Comment: This is a limitation of the deconstruction syntax in the older C# version. I believe what you're looking for exists starting in C# 10. What are you working in that has you stuck in 7.0?

Comment: Your second syntax works fine here:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/UJvDRE  (I realize it's a different C# version)

Comment: @Wyck - you used the same two variables in both calls. I'm always using "success", but the other return variables are new for each subsequent call.

Comment: OK I get what you're tying to do now.  I wrote an answer.

Comment: Thank you @Logarr, I think yours is the correct answer for me. I'm going to re-examine why we're using the version of C# we are (our app only targets Win 10/11, so I'm guessing the latest version _should_ be OK).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's an argument to be made that it's dangerous to reuse variables the way you're trying to. I'd personally prefer to see this:

```
var (alphaSucceeded, alpha) = GetAlpha();
if (alphaSucceeded)
{
    var (getStuffSucceeded, beta, gamma) = GetStuff(alpha);
```

There are many ways to solve this kind of problem.

For example, you could use a monadic library (there are many out there: [this is mine](https://github.com/j2jensen/CallMeMaybe)) to represent the concept of `GetAlpha()` returning a non-value.

```
var alphaMaybe = MaybeGetAlpha();
var stuff = alphaMaybe.Select(alpha => GetStuff(alpha)); // or just.Select(GetStuff)
```

Or, since you're currently only dealing with value types, you could just use `Nullable<>`s. In later versions of C#, you can use nullables with reference types, and also use pattern matching to simplify syntax.

```
if(GetAlpha() is int alpha)
{
  // use alpha
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With judicious use of [*discards*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards) (assigning an underscore `_` as the variable name) you can do it.  And you only need C# 7.  Put new variables in the first tuple and existing variables in the second tuple.  The syntax is longer, but still DRY.

> Which, by the way, stands for *Don't Repeat Yourse*... omg the irony, nevermind.  ;)

```cs
var (success, alpha) = GetAlpha();
if (success)
{
    var (_, beta, gamma) = (success, _, _) = GetStuff(alpha);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would argue this particular case - **where you are interested if the call is successful or not** - is a case where `out` is best suited.

```
private bool GetAlpha(out int alphaOut) {...}
```

I would use the tuple approach only if I'm not interested in the success state.

```
private (int, string) GetAlpha() {}
```

If I need the success state AND I need multiple returns, then I would use both so that I don't have multiple `out` params - which I think is your concern.

```
private bool GetAlpha(out (int, string) tupleAlpha) {...}
```

BTW, I don't think there is anything wrong with `out`. Yes, if you are using it with void methods its unnecessary, or if you are returning multiple `out` (but that's more of a code smell indicating your function is doing too many things). There are plenty of examples of the `out` pattern in the `.NET` API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0

Comment: While `out` params aren't "evil" per se, they do pose problems when it comes to modern patterns like LINQ and Tasks.